# Android Studio FutureTask inside a for loop executing only once

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to do a task and wait for it finish, everything was working fine, but when I try to do the same inside a `for` loop the `FutureTask` is executed only once:

```
for(int i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
            
 /* 
     actions to get an array called arr, 
     but in this code I will just put 20 on this second for loop 
  
 */

  for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 20; i2++){
                
    Runnable action = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //when I add this line which is add a view to a relative layout, it executes only once
                        RelativeLayout main_layout = v.findViewById(R.id.main);
                        main_layout.addView(a_view);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        Log.i("Message" , "Executed");
                    }
                };

    RunnableFuture<Void> task = new FutureTask<>(action , null);
    v.post(task);
    task.get();

  }
}
```

The task is executing once only, it supposed to be repeated 20 times so what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tests, i finally solved this issue, the only thing i had to do was removing the last line `task.get()`

so the code will be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < days.length; i++){


 /* 
     actions to get an array called arr, 
     but in this code i will just put 20 on this second for loop 

 */

  for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 20; i2++){

    Runnable action = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       layout, it excute only once
                        RelativeLayout main_layout = v.findViewById(R.id.main);
                        main_layout.addView(a_view);

                        Log.i("Message" , "Executed");
                    }
                };

    RunnableFuture<Void> task = new FutureTask<>(action , null);
    v.post(task);

    //task.get();  removed

  }
}
```